# How to determine when new devices are added with evdev?

Tags: linux, evdev

What is the preferred way to determine when new devices become available as `/dev/input/eventX`?

Do I have to periodically examine the `/dev/input` directory, comparing my open files against the list of `/dev/input/eventX` devices, or is there a simpler way?

I have taken a brief look at [hotplug.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt), but I think that would notify me of the underlying raw `/dev/input` device creation, and not necessarily the corresponding `/dev/input/eventX` creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inotify.
Something like `inotifywait -r -m /dev/input`

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know about inotify.  I will actually be doing this from code, but this points me in the right direction.